# Integral over difference of two sets

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $S_1,S_2$ be bounded sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:S_1\cup S_2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Show that if $f$ is integrable over $S_1$ and $S_2$, then $f$ is integrable over $S_1-S_2$, and $$\int_{S_1-S_2}f=\int_{S_1}f-\int_{S_1\cap S_2}f.$$

I know there is the result that $f$ is integrable over $S_1\cup S_2$ and over $S_1\cap S_2$, and also the formula $$\int_{S_1\cup S_2}f=\int_{S_1}f+\int_{S_2}f-\int_{S_1\cap S_2}f.$$

But I can't see how to apply this result here.

Also, I tried looking at the proof of this result. For nonnegative $f$ it uses $f_{S_1\cup S_2}(x)=\max\{f_{S_1}(x),f_{S_2}(x)\}$ (where $f_A(x)=f(x)$ if $x\in A$ and $=0$ if $x\not\in A$.), and then the fact that the max function of two integrable functions is integrable. Then for general $f$ it uses $f_+(x)=\max\{f(x),0\}, f_-(x)=\max\{-f(x),0\}$, and $f(x)=f_+(x)-f_-(x)$, and apply linearity.

Might any of this be helpful toward the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $$S_1=(S_1\smallsetminus S_2)\sqcup(S_1\cap S_2)$$

Comment: Still, we can't use that theorem to say anything about $S_1-S_2$. It only goes from $A,B$ to $A\cup B$, not backward, right (i.e. not from $A,A\cup B$ to $B$?

Comment: @MikaH. I don't understand what you mean. We're writing $S_1=S\cup S'$ for some other two sets, with $S\cap S'=\varnothing$. What do you mean by backwards?

Comment: I mean we have the result that if $f$ is integrable over $A$ and over $B$, then it's integrable over $A\cup B$ and $A\cap B$. But we can't use it to conclude that if $f$ is integrable over $A$ and over $A\cup B$, then it's integrable over $B$. (Or can we?)

Comment: @MikaH. Results of this kind are usually stated as "Suppose $A\cap B=\varnothing$. Then $$\int_{A\cup B}=\int_A +\int_B$$ if any two of the integrals exist". That is, if two exists, then the third does an equals what the equation tells you.

Comment: Okay, in my book it's stated as the integral exists over $A\cup B$ if it exists over $A$ and over $B$. Perhaps I should try to prove the missing part myself?

Comment: @MikaH. I am guessing you say that $f$ is integrable over a set $A$ if there is some closed rectangle containing $A$ such that $$\int_R \chi_{A} f$$ exists? Then note that $$\chi_{S_1\setminus S_2}=\chi_{S_1}-\chi_{S_1\cap S_2}$$